# Why does the result come out like this when I use a function?

Tags: c, arguments, printf, function-call

```
#include <stdio.h>

int apple(int total, int ate);

int main(void) {
    printf("If you eat %d out of %d apples, there will be %d left.\n", 
             4, 10, apple(10, 4));
    return 0;
}

int apple(int total, int ate) {
    printf("This is a function with a passing value.\n");
    return total - ate;
}
```

When you debug this program, the result will look like this.

```
This is a function with a passing value.
If you eat 4 out of 10 apples, there will be 6 left.
```

When I interpret it based on what I have learned so far, the result is

```
If you eat 4 out of 10 apples, there will be 6 left.
This is a function with a passing value.
```

It should come out this way, so why is it coming out differently?

I don't think I understand the function order of the C language yet.

Answer (score 2):

In this call

```
printf("If you eat %d out of %d apples, there will be %d left.\n", 
         4, 10, apple(10, 4));
```

at first all arguments are evaluated before passing them to the function.

So this expression

```
apple(10, 4)
```

is evaluated and the function `apple` outputs its message. After that the return value of the function `apple` is used in the call of `printf`.

The call of printf can not output the value `6` in this message

```
If you eat 4 out of 10 apples, there will be 6 left.
                                            ^^^
```

before the function `apple` will be called.